# How to show a quadratic polynomial with complex roots has solutions mod $p$?

Tags: quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

When the discriminant is $-k$ or ${-1\over k}$:
As long as $-1$ and $k$ are both squares $\bmod p$ (trivial) or are both not squares, there are solutions mod $p$. How can this be explained/proven?

e.g.:

$x^2+x+1$ has a discriminant $-3$ and has solutions mod $p$ when $p \equiv (1 \bmod 6)$, which includes $p \equiv (7 \bmod 12)$ where neither $3$ nor $-1$ are squares.

Comment: Don’t call the discriminant $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$: it is $b^2-4ac$. I fixed that. Also, the LaTeX command “mod” is simply awful: it creates ugly extra spaces. Use \bmod. I did that too.

Comment: @KCd Thanks. It looked awful indeed.

Comment: It is not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: @KCd Is therea better way to look at $-3$ than $i\sqrt3$? Otherwise it doesn't seem obvious at all that there should be solutions when neither $k$ or$-1$ are squares. (when only one of the two is a square $\bmod p$ there obviously can't be any solutions.)

Comment: (All numbers assumed non-zero.) Multiplication by a non-square will interchange the sets of squares and non-squares.

Comment: Write $\sqrt{-3}$. Do not break up the square root into $i$ times $\sqrt{3}$. That is an excessive deference to notation from complex numbers. In $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$, $-3 = 4 = 2^2$ is a square but neither $-1$ nor $3$ is a square mod $7$.

Comment: @OlderAmateur Well, you have two obvious non-squares to choose from.

Comment: @WimC FWIW Instead of multiplying the two squares, I was multiplying the roots $i \bmod p$ by $\sqrt 3 \bmod p$ to get   $\sqrt -3 \bmod p$ Hence my confusion about what exactly you meant for me to multiply by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work with an odd prime $p$, and consider the quadratic $a x^2 + b x + c = 0$, where $a \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$. "Completing the square" writes this as
$$ a \left(\left(x + \frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 - \frac{b^2-4 a c}{4a^2}\right) = 0 $$
so there are solutions if and only if $b^2 - 4 a c$ is a quadratic residue (i.e. a square) $\bmod p$.

For example, suppose (as for $x^2 + x + 1$ the discriminant $b^2 - 4 a c = -3$.  For what primes is that a quadratic residue?  Note that $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ (a prime $> 3$) iff either $-1$ and $3$ are both residues or both nonresidues (the product of two quadratic residues or two nonresidues is a residue, while the product of a (nonzero) residue and a nonresidue is
a nonresidue). By the first supplement to the law of quadratic reciprocity, $-1$ is a residue mod $p$ iff $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$.
By quadratic reciprocity, $3$ is a residue mod $p$ iff $p \equiv -1$ or $1 \bmod 12$.
The conclusion is that $-3$ is a residue if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and a nonresidue if $p \equiv 2 \bmod 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it by deriving the quadratic formula mod $p$: when $ax^2 + bx + c$ is a quadratic polynomial with coefficients mod $p$ and discriminant $d := b^2-4ac$, the polynomial has roots mod $p$ if and only if $d$ is a square mod $p$, in which case the roots are $(-b \pm \sqrt{d})/(2a)$, where $\sqrt{d}$ denotes any number mod $p$ that squares to $d \bmod p$.

Comment: How do we determine what primes have squares $d \bmod p$ when $d$ is negative?

Comment: Use quadratic reciprocity. Determining all primes $p > 2$ such that $d \bmod p$ is a square, at least in some concrete examples, is a task discussed in any number theory book that treats quadratics reciprocity.